# How to use nRF24L01 on ATTiny85 and together with serial TX?

Tags: microcontroller, rf, serial, attiny85, nrf24l01

I am using ATTiny85 + nRF24L01 to receive radio messages.
After connecting nRF24L01 to ATTiny85 I don't have much PINs left, as I use all pins except PB5=RST:

```
                         +-\/-+                              
                   PB5  1|o   |8  Vcc --- nRF24L01  VCC 
  nRF24L01  CE --- PB3  2|    |7  PB2 --- nRF24L01  SCK     
  nRF24L01 CSN --- PB4  3|    |6  PB1 --- nRF24L01 MOSI
  nRF24L01 GND --- GND  4|    |5  PB0 --- nRF24L01 MISO
                         +----+
```

I use RF24 https://nrf24.github.io/RF24/
And I want to use SendOnlySoftwareSerial https://github.com/nickgammon/SendOnlySoftwareSerial
To send data to another ATTiny85 that is handling display.

I guess I need to share some pin that is connected to nRF24L01 to use as serial TX. In theory it should not be a problem because I don't need to use serial and radio at the same time. The question is: Which pin to use and how to disable temporary nRF24L01 and switch to serial TX, and how to go back to using nRF24L01?
Or, maybe there is a way to use PB5=RST as digital output to send serial data?

Comment: PB5 can be used as a (weakly driving) IO pin, but you'd lose the ability to reset the micro (e.g. during programming).  If I were you I'd use an ATTiny84 instead which has more IO pins but is still very similar in specs, although the package is larger at 14 pins.

Comment: If you do not toggle SCK you can do whatever you wish with the other NRF24L01 signals. 
|| Without looking up SPI protocol: You can almost certainly use MOSI change of state with SCK idle as a serial select.

Comment: Do you need RXD on serial, too?